# Trouble with understanding JavaScript syntax of chosen plugin, need advice

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-chosen

I want to be a javascript programmer, so I am trying to read and understand the code in [chosen plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/).

I know how to create a jquery plugin, and I have read about the module pattern,
yet this code is unclear to me:

```
  //...
  attaching to jQuery object
  //...
   $.fn.extend({
    chosen: function(options) {

      return $(this).each(function(input_field) {
        if (!($(this)).hasClass("chzn-done")) {
          return new Chosen(this, options);
        }

      });
    }
  });



 //...
 //...
 //...


Chosen = (function() {
    __extends(Chosen, AbstractChosen);
    function Chosen() {
      Chosen.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);


    } 
  // ...
  // attaching various events
  // ...
   return Chosen;
})();
```

If Chosen is a self invoked function - why init it using **new** statement?
Thanks

Comment: Savascript? Is that like a cut-price version of Javascript? `:-D`

Comment: Lol 'savascript syntacsis of choesn'... dyslectics are teople poo.

the new keyword is used, bc Chosen is a self invoked function, that calls an object constructor further up the prototype chain, in other words: chosen is a secondary constructor of the child object.

Comment: Thank you for answer (i run debugger and saw it is exactly what happening) , but now i must ask: why to wrap the Chosen object definition with self invoke?

Comment: p.s. sorry for dislection, i'm not real programmer yet- only want to became one

Answer (score 1):

`Chosen` in the outer scope is the function/constructor returned from the inner scope that comes from the "self invoked function". That's why it's called with `new`.